Unable to override Astra theme's display:none !important style for WooCommerce mini cart remove icon
I'm using the Astra theme with WooCommerce and having an issue with the mini cart's remove icon (X icon). The icon is being hidden by a style rule in Astra's CSS that I cannot override.
Problem:
The following Astra theme style is preventing the WooCommerce mini cart remove icon from displaying:
.ast-mobile-menu-trigger-minimal, 
.menu-toggle.main-header-menu-toggle, 
.ast-button-wrap .menu-toggle, 
.mobile-menu-toggle-icon, 
.ast-mobile-svg, 
.ahfb-svg-iconset {
    display: none !important;
}

What I've tried:
Adding more specific CSS selectors with !important:
body.woocommerce .woocommerce-mini-cart-item a.remove .ahfb-svg-iconset.ast-inline-flex {
    display: inline-flex !important;
}

Using JavaScript to force the display property:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const removeIcons = document.querySelectorAll('.woocommerce-mini-cart-item a.remove .ahfb-svg-iconset');
    removeIcons.forEach(icon => {
        icon.style.setProperty('display', 'inline-flex', 'important');
    });
});

None of these approaches have worked - the display: none !important style from Astra still takes precedence.
Environment:
WordPress Version: 6.6.2
Astra Theme Version: 4.8.1
WooCommerce Version: 9.3.3

Try to put the style in header above the main stylesheet. As you are using !important and it is not working. It means there is same css is written with !important

If you're not on localhost, please share the url of website.

Your approach should work. So I suspect your selector does not pick up your target element, or there is another higher precedence rule you are not aware of.
Another trick would be setting an inline important style to your target element, i.e. giving it a style="display: inline-flex !important;" attribute.
Edit: CSS rules in <style> are higher than ones in stylesheet.

Hi, im sure the selector has targeted the element correctly as it is shown when i inspect element but im not sure why display: none !important is still on higher precedence
screenshot

@ChristianHadiwijaya .ahfb-svg-iconset is defined in the <style> tag of the page, which has a higher precedence that one defined in the stylesheet.

can you try add below additional css!!
.ast-builder-layout-element.site-header-focus-item.ast-header-woo-cart {
    display: none !important;
}

